# MySQL best select multi condition query

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM product_variants WHERE (bottom_type = '$bottom_type1' OR bottom_type = '$bottom_type2' ) AND (bottom_size = '$bottom_size ' ) AND (product_id != '$product_id1 ' OR product_id != '$product_id2' OR product_id != '$product_id3')
```

It is not working as it should, its not giving me the results needed.
What is the best way to build it? 
Thanks

Comment: Don't inject variables into queries. Use prepared statements/parameterized queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just my guess at what you're after. Example table structure, with data and expected results would help answer your question.

```
SELECT * 
FROM product_variants 
WHERE bottom_type IN ('$bottom_type1', '$bottom_type2') 
AND bottom_size = '$bottom_size' 
AND product_id NOT IN ('$product_id1 ', '$product_id2', '$product_id3')
```